# NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:while identifying draggable and droppable element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, webdriver, draggable

I am actually new to selenium. I am trying to do drag and drop operation on a demo website : http://jqueryui.com/droppable/ (Here go to demo-->Droppable).

Following is my html source :

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: relative;">
    <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>
```

Following is my code block :

```
WebElement drag=dr.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='draggable']"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(drag));

WebElement drop=dr.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='droppable']"));

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(drop));
//act.moveToElement(drop).build().perform();
act.dragAndDrop(drag, drop).build().perform();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element to *drag* and the element to *drop* are within an `<iframe>`. So you have to switch to the intended *frame* first then locate the *draggable* and *droppable* elements and perform *dragAndDrop()* as follows :

Here is the complete code snippet :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/droppable/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='demo-frame']")));
WebElement  from = driver.findElement(By.id("draggable"));
WebElement  to = driver.findElement(By.id("droppable"));
new Actions(driver).dragAndDrop(from, to).build().perform();
System.out.println("Drag and Drop Completed");
driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the drag & drop elements are located within an iframe. You need to switch to the iframe with `class='demo-frame'`

Once you switch to the iframe, you can then locate and interact with your element.